# Jest snapshot does not cover component

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, create-react-app

I use CRA and built-in jest unit test library. I've wrote some simple unit test with snapshot, and when test was passed , my coverage was not.

Current Result: when run `npm test` -test passed, when run `npm run test-coverage` - generate coverage folder with html, but only React component does not cover

Expected Result: show coverage when run `npm run test-coverage` for React component with snapshot

**package.json**

```
  "scripts": {
        "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
        "test-coverage": "set CI=true && react-scripts test --coverage --watchAll",
    },
  "jest": {
        "collectCoverageFrom": [
            "src/lib/**/*.{js,jsx}",
            "!**/node_modules/**",
            "!**/coverage/**"
        ],
        "coverageReporters": [
            "text",
            "html"
        ],
        "coverageThreshold": {
            "global": {
                "branches": 80,
                "functions": 80,
                "lines": 80,
                "statements": 80
            }
        }
    }
```

**Button.js**

```
export const Button = ({
    style,
    onClick,
    disabled = false,
    children,
    showSpinner = false,
    className
}) => {
    return (
        <div
            style={style}
            className={cn('button', className)}
            onClick={onClick}
            disabled={disabled}
        >
            {children}
            {showSpinner && (
                <Spinner className='button--spinner' animation='border' />
            )}
        </div>
    );
};

export default withButton(Button);
```

**Butto.test.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import renderer from 'react-test-renderer';
import { Button } from './Button';
import Icon from '../../Icon';


describe('<Button/> ', () => {
    const jsxElement = (
        <>
            <h1>Hello, world!</h1>Icon <Icon name='doctor' />
        </>
    );

    ['string children', <Icon name='doctor' />, jsxElement].forEach(
        children => {
            it('should render children when it was passed', () => {
                const button = renderer.create(<Button>{children}</Button>).toJSON();

                expect(button).toMatchSnapshot();
            });
        }
    );

    it('should render spinner when showSpinner is true', () => {
        const button = renderer.create(<Button showSpinner={true} />).toJSON();

        expect(button).toMatchSnapshot();
    });

    it('should not render spinner by default', () => {
        const button = renderer.create(<Button />).toJSON();

        expect(button).toMatchSnapshot();
    });
});
```

[image]

Based official doc. it should workd
https://jestjs.io/docs/en/snapshot-testing#does-code-coverage-work-with-snapshot-testing

When I run coverage test separately by pattern in terminal I see that component covered 
[image]

Comment: When I deleted coverage folder and re run test-coverage my button was covered. So it's work for me, but still intresting why it did not re create coverage folder structure during new one `test-coverage`run